# what's wrong with this jQuery code?

Tags: jquery

My following code works fine.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.address').click(function() {
            $('#box').slideDown("slow");

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
              url: "details.php",
              success: function(html){              
                 $("#msg").html(html);
                } 
            });

        });
    });
```

However the following does not (only 1 line is changed inside the success:), it loads nothing.. only slidesdown the #box, and #msg inside, however does not load #address.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.address').click(function() {
            $('#box').slideDown("slow"); 

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
              url: "details.php",
              success: function(html){
                $("#msg").html($(html).find('#address').html());
                } 
            });

        });
    });

The details.php is:


<div id="info">some text.</div>
    <div id="address">The address</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you write `$(html)`, you're creating a jQuery object which holds two `<div>` elements.

Calling `.find(...)` on this object searches the *descendants* of the `<div>` elements.
Since neither element has any child elements, i will never find anything.

Instead, you can call `.filter()`, which searches the elements in the set (but not their descendants).

Alternatively, you can wrap the returned HTML in a new `<div>` tag, then call `.find()`.  Since your elements would then be children of the wrapper `<div>`, they'll be found by `.find()`.
Unlike `.filter()`, this will still work if the server is changed to return the `<div>` you're looking for as a child.

Answer (score 1):

jQuerys `.load()`<sup>[help](http://api.jquery.com/load/)</sup> method allows you to load & insert **Page Fragments**:

```
$('a.address').click(function() {
    $('#box').slideDown("slow"); 

    $('#msg').load('details.php #address');
});
```

That is probably what you want to achieve here.